# javascript in onXXX handler escaping of & in parameter

Tags: javascript

i have an <a href> with an onclick javascript. This javascript calls some function in a JS-lib (included in pagehead). What is the correct way (or is it needed) of escaping an & character in the function parameters? Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPop(this,1,'url.pop','m123','&f=a');">
```

vs

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPop(this,1,'url.pop','m123','&amp;f=a');">
```

Or does it depend on the documenttype (html4 / xhtml / html5 / ???) for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="nl" xml:lang="nl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

vs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the best thing to do is stay away from `onXyz` attribute handlers in the first place, not least because of the complexity of dealing with the various layers of text interpretation involved. Instead, use modern event handling. That said:

The text in an attribute **is HTML text**, which it's easy to forget when you're writing JavaScript code in it. :-) To represent an ampersand in HTML, as you indicated, we use `&amp;`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPop(this,1,'url.pop','m123','&amp;f=a');">
<!-- Note --------------------------------------------^^^^^     -->
```

The resulting value of that attribute will be `&f=a`, because the HTML text is interpreted by the browser's HTML parser as it's being read, and the attribute value is set accordingly.

> Or does it depend on the documenttype (html4 / xhtml / html5 / ???)

Nope. `&` is `&amp;` in HTML4, XHTML, and HTML5.

Comment: Thank you very much! The reason for asking is: i'm moving the javascript outside the page to an event handler (using jQuery). The &amp; gives an error at a later point. My exact problem is that i'll have to maintain both versions for some time :( I secretly was hoping both notations were valid... ;)

Comment: @hetOrakel: Oh fun. :-) Yes, in JavaScript code, it has to be `'&f=a'`. Most browsers are tolerant of invalid HTML markup. The HTML5 specification even goes into some detail about what the browser should do if it sees `&` in HTML text followed by something it can't understand as a character entity. So *usually*, you'd get away with `'&f=a'` even in the attribute because the browser will see it's not a valid character entity, back up its parser, and treat it as a literal `&`. But if you happen to write something that can be seen as an entity, that'll bite you.

Comment: @hetOrakel: People accidentally rely on this **all the time**, in URLs. Consider: `<a href="foo?bar=1&baz=2">...</a>` That's invalid. It should be `<a href="foo?bar=1&amp;baz=2">...</a>` But we're constantly doing it, which is why browsers are tolerant.